# Making kernel module fails

Tags: makefile, kernel-module

I am running a custom compiled kernel on a custom arm board. I try to compile a simple kernel module and I get a modpost error.

```
root@****:~/testmod# make
make -C /lib/modules/3.14.52/build M=/root/testmod modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux_3.14.52'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
scripts/mod/modpost: 1: scripts/mod/modpost: �: not found
scripts/mod/modpost: 1: scripts/mod/modpost: ELF: not found
scripts/mod/modpost: 2: scripts/mod/modpost: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make[2]: *** [__modpost] Error 2
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux_3.14.52'
make: *** [all] Error 2
root@****:~/testmod# ls
Makefile  modules.order  test.c  test.o
```

As you see the c file does get compiled but i dont get the ko file. Is my modpost scripts corrupted?

I do get kernel modules compiled when I include it in my kernel source and compile the whole kernel on the host machine.

Heres my makefile too. Pretty simple.

```
obj-m += test.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: `Is my modpost scripts corrupted?` - Looks like that. Just check it content.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Can I replace the scripts folder entirely just like that from another good kernel source?

Comment: Is it cross-platform build? If yes, then you need kernel source/header for target platform (arm based) and toolchain, instead of using default one on your host machine.

Comment: @Eric Sorry I havent understood your answer clearly.
My kernel is cross compiled on the x86 linux host machine from the kernel source for my arm processor by armhf toolchain. Then I installed the compiled zimage dtb on the arm board. I have also included kernel source in the arm board at /usr/src/* and linked it to /lib/modules/*/build.

Comment: Typically target kernel source is put at separated location, instead the one for host build (which could be referenced by "$shell uname -r").  Anyway based on the log, the build did enter /usr/src/linux_3.14.52, so it's not an issue.  Few items to check, 1. toolchain and arch/CROSS_COMPILE setup properly.  2. a prebuilt kernel that contains the configuration and header files used in the build. Also, the kernel must have been built with modules enabled, either do one kernel full build or "make modules_prepare" under source tree should solve most of problems.

Comment: @Eric As I already mentioned compiling the kernel source on the host is not the issue. I do make the kernel and install it. Kernel building is not the problem also modules are compiled when I am on host setting arch, crosscompile and toolchain. But I want to compile kernel modules inside that kernel when Im on the target machine. Thats when the error occurs.